# Ubuntu on Dell Latitude E5520 working slow

Tags: firefox, 12.10, performance

I know it's a little vague, but.
 I really need your help.

I have Ubuntu 12.10 on Dell Latitude E5520 i5 2410M with 4GB RAM & 500 GB HDD.
With Firefox (16.0.2) it is extremely frustrating to do anything - even when I now opened the about dialog - it took 3 seconds. Occasionally when I type this message the GUI freezes. By the way, the HDD light on the laptop is on about 50% of the time.
Simplest tasks can take few seconds - accessing a folder for the first time, viewing images, browsing the Dash menu, and even working in terminal seems to stress the computer to it's limit.
Needless to say I am not running any heavy software - just Firefox and some folders..

I should also note that 2 months ago everything was ok. I went traveling then for 6 weeks, and it seems that since I came back - it started.

I added the 'free' and 'top' output, if anything else is needed please let me know.
Thanks!

```
Here is free:
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4029164    3212280     816884          0     110620    2343148
-/+ buffers/cache:     758512    3270652
Swap:      1998844          0    1998844
```

and top:

```
top - 13:49:03 up 47 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.94, 1.35, 1.42
Tasks: 198 total,   2 running, 196 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  2.2 us,  0.6 sy,  0.0 ni, 81.6 id, 15.6 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   4029164 total,  3246036 used,   783128 free,   110816 buffers
KiB Swap:  1998844 total,        0 used,  1998844 free,  2381608 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
 3551 elad      20   0  689m 272m  35m S   4.9  6.9   1:52.08 firefox           
 3601 elad      20   0  253m  36m  18m S   2.6  0.9   0:22.42 plugin-containe   
 1207 root      20   0 40292  15m 5064 S   1.1  0.4   1:34.47 Xorg              
 2467 elad      20   0  275m  87m  30m S   0.8  2.2   0:55.01 compiz            
 3589 elad      20   0 80016  12m 9848 S   0.8  0.3   0:03.64 unity-webapps-c   
 2426 elad      20   0  6064 3020  772 S   0.5  0.1   0:04.03 dbus-daemon       
 3903 elad      20   0  103m  15m  11m S   0.5  0.4   0:01.74 gnome-terminal    
 2528 elad      20   0 38796 2600 2176 S   0.2  0.1   0:00.18 gvfs-afc-volume   
 2666 elad      20   0  105m  18m  11m S   0.2  0.5   0:11.49 unity-panel-ser   
 2770 elad      20   0 43816 6984 5632 S   0.2  0.2   0:00.30 mission-control   
 3510 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.2  0.0   0:00.33 kworker/0:2       
 3643 elad      20   0 80064  12m 9924 S   0.2  0.3   0:00.93 unity-webapps-c   
 3901 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.2  0.0   0:00.13 kworker/u:2       
 3963 elad      20   0  5204 1392 1012 R   0.2  0.0   0:00.22 top               
    1 root      20   0  3720 2164 1316 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.62 init              
    2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd          
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.41 ksoftirqd/0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you experience this problem mostly when using Firefox, try disabling "Global Menu Bar integration" from Firefox add-ons. This, supposedly, is a more common issue if you have a lot of bookmarks. I had a very similar problem, and disabling that add-on fixed it for me.

Bug that I refer to > https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/987060

If you notice Firefox, unity-panel-service and hud-service taking up a lot of RAM and CPU, this is likely your problem. I noticed that your resources seem to be fine in what you posted, but that is only an instantaneous report and might not be an accurate account.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd take a wild guess and say you installed it using wubi.exe on windows 7 OS. If so, you may manage to solve your problem by something that worked exquisitely for me. Namely, removing your Ubuntu 12.10 via use of uninstall.exe in the file directory /ubuntu (of course backing up all your files prior to doing so) and then inserting a live CD, rebooting and booting from CD. (Pressing F12 if this option doesn't come up automatically)

Incidentally if you need to create a live CD just install the .iso file from http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=latest for 32 bit OS and http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=latest for 64 bit OS and burn it to a CD with ~800MB free space.

Comment: I do not have Windows OS on my laptop.. just linux

Comment: Well then as far as my knowledge goes you're flipped, sorry. I'll let someone else field this question. Just leaving my answer here because I'm sure there's some people with a similar question that may read your question so its worth leaving this answer here.